# Peano axioms and natural numbers

Tags: real-analysis, recurrence-relations, natural-numbers

Suppose I have an ordered field $F$ and $1 \in F$. Then we define the set of natural numbers recursively, here we call it $\mathbb{N}_F$ in the field $F$ via

$1 ∈ \mathbb{N}_F$, and if $\textbf{n} \in \mathbb{N}_F $ then $\textbf{n}+1 ∈ \mathbb{N}_F$, and $\textbf{n} = 1+ .... +1$, where the right side has $n$ "ones".

I want to prove this recurrence relation satisfies the Peano axioms. These kinds of questions look so basic so I don't what tools should I use to prove it/... I just know $\mathbb{N}_F$ is defined as an element $1$ and some successors to complete the set.

$1.$For proving 1 is not the successor of any $k$ ∈ $\mathbb{N}_F$. I am thinking contradiction and showing that there is some $k ∈ \mathbb{N}_F$, and I have that $k+1=1$ (since its a successor). But I don't know what to state next, I know I cannot explicitly define $0$ since it's not an element of $\mathbb{N}_F$.

$2.$ For proving if $\textbf{n},\textbf{m} ∈ \mathbb{N}_F$, and $\textbf{m}+1=\textbf{n}+1$, then $\textbf{n}=\textbf{m}$, this also seems obvious for me but I don't know how to prove it rigorously, as I don't know how to get rid of the $1$ on each side. Maybe I have to apply the fact that its an ordered field but I don't know where to start

$3.$ For $S ⊆ \mathbb{N}_F$, I want to show that $S=\mathbb{N}_F$ if i) $1 ∈ S$ and ii) if $\textbf{n} ∈ S$, then $\textbf{n}+1∈S$

Here I know that $S⊆\mathbb{N}_F$ is already assumed and I only have to prove that $\mathbb{N}_F⊆S$, but its very obvious since $S$ is defined exactly like $\mathbb{N}_F$ but how do I write it formally?

Any inputs are appreciated!

Comment: Your definition of $\Bbb{N}_F$ is unclear as you are using $n$ both for a member of $F$ and for an ordinary natural number (when you say $n$ ones). If you define it in terms of the closure property $n \in \Bbb{N}_F \implies n + 1 \in \Bbb{N}_F$, then you need to say that it is the smallest set containing $1$ and satisfying the closure property. If you say it comprises $1$ and all elements of the form $1 + \ldots + 1$, then1, 2 and 3 all hold. If you clarify your definition, we can give you some more help with the proofs.

Comment: @RobArthan I wrote $\textbf{n}$ when it is $\in \mathbb{N}_F$ and not bold when it is in the counting number I suppose, and yes, it's defined in terms of the closure property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define the successor function: $s(n) = n+1$. (Then the simplest definition of $\mathbb{N}_F$ would be as the smallest subset of $F$ that contains $1$ and is closed under $s$. This gives you (3) just by definition.)

You condition (2) follows from the axioms of a field: Assuming that $m,n\in\mathbb{N}_F$ are such that $s(m)=s(n)$ translates into $m+1=n+1$ in $F$. Adding $-1$ (by definition: the additive inverse of $1\in F$) to each side of this equation gives $m=n$, as desired.

To show that $1\ne s(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_F$, you need to use that the characteristic of $F$ is zero. Try it yourself.

Comment: Ok so since $\mathbb{N}_F \subset F$ I can just use any field properties and order to prove these axioms? (I suppose that is where the $-1$ comes from) and should I prove that the $-1$ exists or that is redundant?

Comment: @JayEstrera Yes, you need to use the field axioms (else indeed you have nothing at all to work with).

One of the axioms of a field is that there exists an element which is neutral with respect to addition (and it is a one-line proof to show that no more than one such element can exist). We denote this element by $0$. Another axiom is that for every element $x\in F$ there is an element $y$ such that $x+y= 0$ (and again it is easy to prove that this element is unique). We call this element $-x$. Yet another axiom tells you that $1\in F$. 

Ergo: $-1$ exists in $F$.

Comment: thanks! for (3), can I also use induction to show that every element of N_F is an element of S?

Comment: If you define $\mathbb{N}_F$ as I suggested then there is (almost) nothing to prove. Formally, you define it as the intersection of all subsets of $F$ that contain $1$ and are closed under the map $s:F\to F$, $s(x)=x+1$. Then any $S\subset F$ these two properties satisfies $\mathbb{N}_F\subset S$. So if, in addition, $S\subset \mathbb{N}_F$ then $S=\mathbb{N}_F$.